# How to access outside .this in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, this, module-pattern

I'm trying to rewrite my functional code to module pattern js, and I have this issue - When I try to delete input field which is dynamically created, I use jQuery  `$(this)` to access dom element and delete its parent `'div`'. But this refers to the Modal object, not the component I clicked. How to solve it, without making some field counter and creating fields with unique ID's, then catching ids on click and deleting that input field?

**My modal:**

```
var s,
    Modal = {
        settings: {
            addInputBtn: $("#add-input"),
            inputContainer: $("#modal-input-form"),
            checkBoxesList: $(".check-box"),
            inputFieldsList: $(".form-control"),
            inputFieldsOptionalList: $(".optional-modal"),
            inputHtml: `
                <div class="input-group mb-3 optional-modal">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="check-box">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <button type="button" class="close">
                        <span>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>`
        },
        init: function () {
            s = this.settings;
            this.bindUIActions();
        },

        bindUIActions: function () {
            s.addInputBtn.on("click", () => Modal.addInput());
            s.inputContainer.on("click", ".close", () => Modal.deleteInput());
        },

        addInput: function () {
            s.inputContainer.append(s.inputHtml);
        },

        deleteInput: function () {);
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        }
    }
    Modal.init();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
deleteInput: function (e) {);
            $(e.target).parent('div').remove();
        }
```

Event handlers are passed an event argument. Among its useful properties is `target`, which is the html element that the event originated on. Note that it could be different from the `this` of the event handler, which is the element that the event handler is attached to, as events bubble up through the DOM. So if you have this html:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

then for this JS function:

```
$("#parent").on('click', function(e){
  //this will equal <div id="parent"> unless you bind the handler to something else
  //e.target will equal the clicked element:
  //if the user clicked the child, it will equal the child;
  //if the user clicked parent directly, it will equal parent.
  $(e.target).closest('#parent').doSomething();
});
```

Comment: in `bindUIActions: function ()` - `s.inputContainer.on("click", ".close", (e) => Modal.deleteInput(e));` and `deleteInput: function (e) {e.target.closest("div").remove()}` solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with:

```
deleteInput: function () {;
        $(this.settings).parent('div').remove();
}
```

Also you have a typo at `deleteInput: function () { ); ... the rest of the code`, delete that extra `)` after function. I suggest you trying $(this.settings).. because, `this` gets the Modal, and then you need to access the other object inside that object, which is `settings`. So your modal object, consists of other object, and I'm thinking this way you should be able to get it :)

Comment: Sorry but, if I try  `console.log(this.settings);` in `deleteInput: function ()` it gives me just a list of settings in my Module.